# Selenium Grid Specifications

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have been researching WebDriver's JSON Wire Protocol but this does not seem to include how to interact with the grid i.e. POST /wd/hub/register etc. Do you know where I can find the specifications of Selenium Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information found in the [Selendroid Wiki](http://selendroid.io/scale.html) and using a handy-dandy debugger I managed to figure out how it works, so here goes:

- Download the Standalone-Server jar and start it from terminal using the following command

  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub
- Start your WebDriver implementation
- Prepare a file with the configuration as described in the [Selendroid Wiki](http://selendroid.io/scale.html) page and changing ports and urls according to your configuration
- Send a register request to the hub using the following terminal command:

  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @node-config.json http://localhost:4444/grid/register
- Use the Selenium grid as you wish